# Kirchoff's Laws and Maxwell Laws

Tags: circuit-analysis, electromagnetism, kirchhoffs-laws

If I want to use Kirchoff's Laws in a electrical circuit, I should assume that wavelength is greater than circuit dimensions. But this wavelength is from which wave?

I know that it is related with some maxwell equations like:

[image: Equations]

so which wave is this?

Comment: Could you enumerate the list out of which you want us to pick "which wave"?  Pick a frequency and a speed (because the speed of EM propagation in PCB material is different than it is in air), and calculate the wavelength.  Then you're done.

Comment: I read that the wavelength should be greater than circuit dimensions. but this wavelength is from which wave? I have doubt about this

Comment: This is the wavelength of your input signal.

Comment: Voting to close because the phrase "which wave" is too vague, and the OP refuses to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Kirchoffs laws you need to assume that the maximum wavelength of any signal that is relevant for the analysis is significantly greater in wavelength than your circuit board's maximum dimension (to avoid significant error). Signal wavelength examples in free-space: -

- 300 MHz has a \$\lambda\$ of 1 metre
- 30 MHz has a \$\lambda\$ of 10 metre
- 3 MHz has a \$\lambda\$ of 100 metre

As a signal on your circuit board and due to the PCB material, you should assume that \$\lambda\$ may be as low as half the free-space values quoted above.

Comment: "of any signal that is relevant for the analysis" which signals are these and how they interfere in analysis?

Comment: @VictorCoutinho Those signals that you wish to apply K-laws to. I don't know specifically what they are but you must do else why do a K-analysis?

Comment: I'm just seeking for information about those signals, I know that above a frequency i should use Maxell Laws.

Comment: @VictorCoutinho I don't know what you expect me to add other than generalisms. If you want to analyse a signal then you must have some idea about what that signal is and its frequency. I have absolutely no idea what that signal is. It has to be defined by you. I've given you examples so isn't that good enough to get you started?